# PostGIS wrapped function is valid, but never returns

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to create a function that will return the nearest bathroom to a location - due to some constraints, it needs to be in a function that returns a `SETOF` values.  I've been able to get a function to do that - but when I run it with a value, it never returns.

Meanwhile running the inner query on its own returns just fine ...

Here's the function I've created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nearest_bathroom(tag integer, max_distance decimal = 0.1 )
RETURNS SETOF bathrooms AS $$
SELECT bathroom.*
FROM bathroom
WHERE bathroom.id IN
(
        SELECT broom.id
        FROM bathroom broom
          INNER JOIN location l
          ON _st_dwithin(broom.geom, l.geom, max_distance)
        WHERE l.tag = tag
        ORDER BY st_distance(broom.geom, l.geom)
        LIMIT 1
)
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Meanwhile running the query outside the function (`SELECT bathroom.*` etc.) with a value for `tag` works just fine, and returns in milliseconds.

I should add that I see the same problem when creating a function that `RETURNS TABLE (etc, )` instead of `SETOF`.

Comment: Assuming that `id` is the primary key (or just a key) the outer query is not needed.

Comment: Trying to return a SETOF gives an untyped error unless I'm returning the entire table - basically this fails . .. .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
RETURNS SETOF closest AS
SELECT bathroom.id, bathroom.name, st_distance(bathroom.geom, l.geom, max_dsitance) as distance
```

on the join.  I'd actually prefer to do it that way, but that errors as closest isn't defined.

Comment: And another thing... In the inner query you wrote `SELECT bathroom.id` but aliased `bathroom` as `broom`. Hence `bathroom.id` gets bound to the outer queries value. Unless the inner query returns no result, the overall query returns just all rows from `bathroom`.

Comment: Mistype, it's actually SELECT broom.id in the inner.

Comment: I implied to change the `SELECT` list to `*` when putting the inner query as only query.

Comment: So you didn't post the actual function? Makes it a bit hard to try and answer the question...

Comment: You're suggesting to change Select broom.id to Select * in the inner query?  That's not going to work.

Comment: Nah, I suggest to take the inner query, change the list to `*` and use the resulting query as the **only** query. Unless `id` is not a key, there is no need for another query around the inner query, which actually already selected the row you want.

Comment: ah, make much more sense!

Unfortunately it still has the same issue - the inner query works fine, however invoking the function (which creates without issue) never returns.

Comment: to note - same behavior is seen when substituting RETURNS TABLE (etc, ) for SETOF.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `st_dwithin` and not `_st_dwithin`. The latter function cannot use an index.

Then make sure that the geometry column on the bigger table has a GiST index.

If both tables are big, performance will never be great, because the only join strategy for such a join is nested loops.

As sticky bit said, you should get rid of the outer query.

Comment: There is a GiST index - what's very odd is that the queries run just fine on their own (avg return of about 32 ms), but once within a function take long enough to time out (60+ seconds).  I'm not understanding why having st_distance would do this - if the function is written without it, even with st_within, it works fine.

Comment: Use `auto_explain` with `log_nested_statements` to get the execution plan (ideally with analyze) and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue - for some reason named parameters were not being evaluated.  Switching my variable use to $1, $2, etc fixed this - which also fixed the timeout which was being caused by trying to run distance functions on the huge unlimited cartesian.